# Unable to install node using nvm on windows

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install multiple versions of nodejs on my machine by first installing nvm for windows and then using nvm command to install the specific versions of nodejs from the command prompts

When i try this

```
nvm install 7.3.0 64
```

I get error

Could not retrieve https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/SHASUMS256.txt

Could somebody tell me why am i getting this error. I tried the above command using administrator command prompt as well the command prompt  in my visual studio but the same result

Answer (score 28):

Likely it means you are behind a proxy server.

To tell nvm about it you need to run the command:

```
nvm proxy [url of your proxy server]
```

For example

```
nvm proxy http://example.com:8080
```

For docs on that command and other nvm for windows commands see https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#usage

Comment: I tried the same as the above and still get the same error.

Comment: It could possibly be some other network related issue. Also, I've had a case where running `nvm off` and then `nvm on` has fixed it after making config changes.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give that a go, I went ahead installed the latest LTS to get my project up and running on my dev server but it's a dev server so i'd like to have the option of switching versions easily.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting same issue but I added `v` as prefix before the actual version number and it worked like a charm.

Try this `nvm install v12.19.0 64`.

Comment: this one works! thanks you and God

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error that could not retrieve https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/SHASUMS256.txt
during installing a different version of nodeJS.

`nvm install latest` worked fine when I disconnected from VPN and open PowerShell in admin mode.

Comment: We use VPN software called perimeter81 and the above worked if I both disconnected AND quit the app. (Would not allow with app open even if disconnected)

Answer (score 2):

Same problem and my solution was:

```
nvm off
nvm on
nvm install lts 64
nvm use newest
```

And for check:

```
nvm list
node -v
npm -v
```

Comment: worked for me. I'm guessing it didn't have permissions, but instead of telling us that, it instead outputted an incredibly wrong and misleading error message to lead us all astray. Gotta love open source.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread; just want to say it's still relevant. I got the same "could not retrieve" error with my first try at installing, then typed "nvm off" and then "nvm on" at the command line and finally tried again: "nvm install latest". Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your nvm using the installer from here: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your command line as administrator and type this line

```
nvm proxy [http-proxy]:[port]
```

Example: `nvm proxy http:bugsareloop.co.ao:3200`

For more details go to : https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/315

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors as on the top on mye windows machine and for me it worked to switch from stable to lts like this:

```
nvm install lts            
nvm use lts
```

Answer (score -2):

Just download zip version of node and extract it to installed folder of nvm and rename node folder to v* (v16.17.1 , v18.9.0 , ...)