# Use nvm behind the corporate firewall

Tags: node.js, proxy, nvm

Since I am behind the corporate firewall, unable to install Node JS via nvm. I decided to use fiddler for proxying and then try to configure proxy in nvm as follows

> nvm proxy http://127.0.0.1:8888 where 8888 is the proxy port in fiddler

However running nvm proxy still returns "none" and still get the timeout when I try to install latest node.

There is a related article: [Unable to install node using nvm on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643043/unable-to-install-node-using-nvm-on-windows?rq=1)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 29):

Solution for Windows:

Make sure you run the nvm proxy command in **Windows PowerShell/Command Prompt as Administrator** (right click Windows PowerShell -> Run as administrator). Else the proxy won't be set!

```
nvm proxy http://127.0.0.1:8888   -> to set
nvm proxy                         -> to see current proxy
nvm proxy none                    -> to clear proxy
```

More info: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Solution for Linux:

1.Edit this file

```
nano ~/.curlrc
```

2.Add this line to the file

```
proxy = user:psw@host:port
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Should be marked as an accepted answer.

Comment: This nothing changed for me. The problem still appears even though the proxy settings are correctly persisted in the settings.txt file

Answer (score 3):

On windows I did like this:

found the file:C:\Users...seu usuario ...\AppData\Roaming\nvm\settings.txt

and added the following line:  proxy: user:psw@host:port

Answer (score 1):

Just set the environment variables

```
set HTTP_PROXY=localhost:8888
set HTTPS_PROXY=localhost:8888
```