# how to update reactjs project to nodejs v18.12.0 and npm v8.19.2?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I installed nodejs 18.12.0 and I want to run my reactjs project, after `npm start` it gives me this errors:

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/assets/images/arrow_vector.svg

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at getHashDigest (E:\project\KhazaeiCRM-main\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\getHashDigest.js:46:34)
at E:\project\KhazaeiCRM-main\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:113:11
at String.replace ()
at interpolateName (E:\project\KhazaeiCRM-main\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:110:8)
at Object.loader (E:\project\KhazaeiCRM-main\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:29:48)

---

after some research, they told me that must install lower version of nodejs,
so I install nodejs 16 and new error is:

Error: PostCSS plugin postcss-import requires PostCSS 8

---

the solution is to install latest version of nodejs !!

what can I do to update my reactjs project to the latest nodejs version ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use nvm to easy choose other node.js version to run app.

Comment: I have tried it. after nvm install 18 , the error was : nvm Could not retrieve https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/SHASUMS256.txt  . is a proxy problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643043/unable-to-install-node-using-nvm-on-windows  try it

Comment: I saw that, I don't use any proxy url